# ModRewrite rule works on ::1 but not on production server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

after hours of struggling, hope sb can help...

I have URL like this:

```
    www.domain.com/entry/some-unimportant-text-788
```

which I want to be rewritten to:

```
    www.domain.com/entry.php?entryID=788
```

My rule looks like so:

```
    RewriteRule ^entry/.+?-([1-9][0-9]*)$ entry.php?entryID=$1 [L]
```

But it is rewritten to:

```
    www.domain.com/entry.php/some-unimportant-text-788
```

So it does not catch the "([1-9][0-9]*)" part at all. Where am I wrong? Maybe it's just a single lil' thing I'm missing ... g===gle was not my friend this time, tried for hours.

Thanks !!

Comment: We can’t possibly answer that with the little information you have given so far. Are you using some sort of CMS? Because the second URL that you say your request gets rewritten to uses the PATH_INFO “syntax”, which is quite a common fallback in a lot of CMS if mod_rewrite is not available. So it might be the CMS rewriting your URLs (maybe in the HTML source of the pages already) – but that single RewriteRule you have shown for sure doesn’t.

Comment: CBroe, no CMS at all. Just direct php-code! And I know that mod_rewrite is available; the file IS called though, but no entryID is being passed to it :-(

Comment: And does that PHP code issue any redirects, and/or is it creating links in the HTML output dynamically?

Comment: no redirects. I did a var_dump($_SERVER) at the very top of the file to see whats going on. so the file IS called, but "the wrong way"

Comment: So what URL do you originally request, and how – do you type it into the address bar, do you follow a link somewhere, …?

Comment: same result no matter what I do. it happens no matter if I click a link or type it directly... no clue whats going wrong. Also did var_dump($_GET), no entryID. But if I rewrite anything **without a forward slash in the original request**, it works. e.g rewriting entry.php?foo=([a-z]*) to something else works!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that at the beginning of your `.htaccess`, to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of MultiViews too – but would that issue an external redirect, that includes the original PATH_INFO? I though MultiViews only worked “internally”.

Comment: No, MultiViews work when the requested file does not exist. Finally say that this is my only idea for this problem :-)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how would that explain that the request gets _rewritten_ to `www.domain.com/entry.php/some-unimportant-text-788`, as the OP stated?

Comment: @CBroe "rewritten" in the test, not in the browser URL (I think !)

Comment: So you think there is no typo and no synatx error in my rewrite rule? Then  I must contact the admin of my webspace, I suppose. With Croises' answer it seems that modRewrite does really NOT work properly. A URL with slashes is obviousely seen as a path, and NOT rewritten, very strange...

Comment: @Sunset this .htaccess is in your root directory, not in `entry/` ?

Comment: @Sunset Yes, for me there is no typo and no syntax error in your rewrite rule

Comment: Croises, yes, it's in the root.As stated, on good ol' localhost everything works like a charm

Comment: Try also with: `DirectorySlash Off ` and with `RewriteBase /`